Is $0$ an eigenvalue for this operator?
I’m learning about the spectrum of a general operator and in this case I’m dealing with the integral operator with $K(x,y) = xy +\operatorname{sin}(x-y)$. To see if $0$ is an eigenvalue, I see what it would mean that the respective eigenfunction would have to be in the orthogonal complement of the slice functions, $k(y) = xy+\operatorname{sin}(x-y)$ for $x$, $y$ in $[0,1]$.Update: I am trying to find a form of such an eigenfunction and so far I believe that something that is odd around 1/2 could work.

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

We have
$$ (Tf)(x)=\int\limits_0^1[xy+\sin(x-y)]f(y)\,dy\\  =
\left (\int\limits_0^1y\,f(y)\,dy \right )\,x+ \left (\int\limits_0^1\cos y\,f(y)\,dy \right )\,\sin x-\left (\int\limits_0^1\sin y\, f(y)\,dy \right )\,\cos x$$
The operator is three dimensional. Moreover, the formula for $T$ implies that
the entire space can be decomposed into the orthogonal sum of two subspaces invariant for $T$, namely $$V:={\rm span}\,(x,\,\sin(2\pi x,\,\cos (2\pi x\}$$ and $V^\perp.$ We have $T\mid _{V^\perp}=0.$ Thus $$\sigma(T)=\{0\}\cup \sigma(T\mid_V)$$
In order to determine $\sigma(T\mid_V)$ we may find the $3\times 3$ matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $x\,,\sin(2\pi x)$ and $\cos(2\pi x)$ and find its eigenvalues. The functions $x\,,\sin(2\pi x)$ and $\cos(2\pi x)$ are not orthogonal, but this is not essential (actually the last two functions are orthogonal to each other). In general if an operator $T$ maps $v_1,\,v_2,\,v_3$ into the linear span of these elements then $$ Tv_j=a_{1j}v_1+a_{2j}v_2+a_{3j}v_3$$ Then we have to find the eigenvalues of the matrix $\{a_{ij}\}.$

Thanks. What do you mean when you say that the set (x,sin(x), cos(x)) is a basis for L2 on [0,1]?. Does this mean that you can write any function in the space as a linear combination of only these three functions?

Corrected. I meant the basis of the range of $T.$

also, how can you be sure that there will be some eigenfunction for 0 which is in the span of those 4 functions you mentioned after expressing the operator as a combination of integrals ?

Let $M$ denotes this four dimensional space. Let $N$ denote the three dimensional space spanned by $x,$ $\sin x$ and $\cos x.$ The operator $T$ maps $M$ into $N.$ Thus the kernel of $T$ restricted to $M$ must be nontrivial, because the dimension of $M$ is larger than the dimension of $N.$

oh I see, it is sufficient to consider the restriction of the operator on a way smaller subspace of L2(0,1). I have constructed the matrix of that smaller domain transformation and I can only see that the only real value eigenvalue is 0. Would this mean that the other imaginary ones dont correspond to any real valued function ? Also, how can I be sure that there are no more eigenvalues of the bigger domain operator ? Could it not be the case that I can find other smaller subspace like the Span of the nth monomials and see that the respective matrix has eigenvalues ?
